# How to perm two different actions on clicking the same button first time and second time in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a quiz using jQuery. It shows one question at a time. On clicking "Next Button" first time, I wanted to highlight the correct and wrong answers and then clicking again on the Next Button second time should take me to the next slide.

But am unable to identify, 1st and second clicks of the Next Button in the slide. Looks like both the actions are happening one after the other immediately and so the first action, user is unable to see.

Below is my code. showNextSlide() is where I am trying to achieve the above mentioned scenario

```
<body class="quiz">
        <h1>Quiz on Important Facts</h1>
        <div class="quiz-container">
          <div id="quiz"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="previous">Previous Question</button>
        <button id="next">Next Question</button>
        <button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
        <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

Script -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var quizContainer = $('#quiz');
  var resultsContainer = $('#results');
  var submitButton = $('#submit');
  var output = [];
  var mq ='';
  const previousButton = $("#previous");
 // const checkAnsweButton = $("#check");
  const nextButton = $("#next");
  var total = '';
  var currentSlide = 0;


  function buildQuiz(){ 

      $.ajax({
        url: './json/qa.json',
        success: function(data){

          //console.log(data.myQuestions);
            mq = data.myQuestions;
            mq.forEach(
              (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
                const answers = [];
                for(letter in currentQuestion.answers){
                  answers.push(
                    `<label>
                      <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
                      ${letter} :
                      ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
                    </label>`
                  );
                }
                output.push(
                  `<div class="slide">
                    <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
                    <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
                  </div>
                  `
                );
                quizContainer.html(output.join(''));
                const slides = $('#quiz').find(".slide");
                total = slides.length;
                showSlide(currentSlide);
              });
        }

    })        
  }

  buildQuiz();


  function showResults() {

    // gather answer containers from our quiz
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.find('.answers');

    // keep track of user's answers
    let numCorrect = 0;

    // for each question...
    mq.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

        // find selected answer
        const answerContainer = answerContainers.eq(questionNumber);
        const selector = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
        const userAnswer = (answerContainer.find(selector) || {}).val();
        //console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').val())
        // if answer is correct
        if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) { 
            // add to the number of correct answers
            numCorrect++;
        }
    });
    $(resultsContainer).html(`${numCorrect} out of ${mq.length}`);
  }


  function showSlide(n) {
    console.log(mq);
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n).addClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n-1).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n+1).removeClass('active-slide');
    currentSlide = n;

    if (currentSlide === 0) {
        previousButton.hide();
    } else {
        previousButton.show();
    }
    if (currentSlide === total - 1) {
        nextButton.hide();
        submitButton.show();
    } else {
        nextButton.show();
        submitButton.hide();
  }
}

function showNextSlide() {
  var clickcount = 0;
  const answerContainers = quizContainer.find('.answers');


    mq.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

        // find selected answer
        const answerContainer = answerContainers.eq(questionNumber);
        const selector = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
        const userAnswer = (answerContainer.find(selector) || {}).val();
        // if answer is correct
        if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
          console.log("if")
            // color the answers green
            answerContainers.find('input').eq(questionNumber).parent().css("color","lightgreen");
        }
        // if answer is wrong or blank
        else {
            // color the answers red
            answerContainers.find('input').eq(questionNumber).parent().css("color","red");
        }
    });
    showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  }

  function showPreviousSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }

  submitButton.on('click', showResults);
  previousButton.on("click", showPreviousSlide);
  //checkAnsweButton.on('click', showResults);
  nextButton.bind("click", showNextSlide);
})
```

JSON -

```
   {
  "myQuestions" : [
    {
      "question": "Who invented JavaScript?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Douglas Crockford",
        "b": "Sheryl Sandberg",
        "c": "Brendan Eich"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "c"
    },
    {
      "question": "Which one of these is a JavaScript package manager?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Node.js",
        "b": "TypeScript",
        "c": "npm"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "c"
    },
    {
      "question": "Which tool can you use to ensure code quality?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Angular",
        "b": "jQuery",
        "c": "RequireJS",
        "d": "ESLint"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "d"
    }
  ]
}
```

JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/01bxu9fv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following: declare the variable `clickcount` outside of the `showNextSlide()` function and check for its value inside of the function, so the right and wrong answers will be displayed upon the first click and the next Slide will be shown upon the second click. If the value of `clickcount` is 2, reset it to 0.

```
 var clickcount = 0;

 function showNextSlide() {

    if(clickcount == 2){
      clickcount = 0;
    }

    if(clickcount == 0) {
       const answerContainers = quizContainer.find('.answers');
       mq.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

          // find selected answer
          const answerContainer = answerContainers.eq(questionNumber);
          const selector = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
          const userAnswer = (answerContainer.find(selector) || {}).val();
          // if answer is correct
          if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
             console.log("if")
             // color the answers green
             answerContainers.find('input').eq(questionNumber).parent().css("color","lightgreen");
        }
    // if answer is wrong or blank
       else {
        // color the answers red
               answerContainers.find('input').eq(questionNumber).parent().css("color","red");
        }
     });
   }
   else {
     showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
   }

   clickcount += 1;
 }
```

Comment: This is working only for the first slide. But it has to work for every slide i.e for every question. Can you please take a look again

Comment: here is a fiddle for reference - https://jsfiddle.net/01bxu9fv/ please help

Comment: @AnUser Can't recreate the problem with the Fiddle as the Fiddle displays all questions on one slide and doesn't have the full functionality.Can you make a Fiddle that works and shows the issue?

Comment: Sorry. Here is the working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ost2ypxj/4/

Comment: @AnUser Can't reproduce the problem, the navigation with the "next" button is working fine. What isn't working is the check if the answer is right because currently it's checking all questions/answers at once because of "mq.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber)". Check the console messages here: https://jsfiddle.net/wev4fpxL/

Comment: Thanks your answer fixed the issue that I reported.

Comment: how do I check for each right answer out of the loop? Can you please help in fixing this too.

Comment: I am thinking we need to use map without the need of for loop but i need help on syntax

Comment: @AnUser I don't have the time at the moment as I need to leave soon, but here's what I came up with https://jsfiddle.net/wev4fpxL/1/ It's a workaround using a data-attribute so each slide has the questionnumber on it and only the current question gets checked in the loop. I also fixed the problem with highlighting the right answer as previously the input with the index of the questionnumber was marked as the right answer, now it is the input with the value of the right answer. Sorry I can't be of more help at the moment.

Comment: @AnUser I have it solved here: https://jsfiddle.net/wev4fpxL/2/ The each loop is now not necessary anymore.